# Being given illegal start of type when I compile

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm fairly new to programming in java and new to concepts like array lists. I'm writing a program for class but I've been stuck on this issue for a few days. When I compile this code, I receive "Illegal start of type". I have spent hours looking over it and trying to figure it out.
I recieve the issue at the carrot

```
 {  
     System.out.print(CO2<i>.gasWaste^());   
 }
```

gasWaste is a method in the CO2Footprint class that returns a double based on info given in the arraylist.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
/**
* Write a description of class CO2FootprintTester here.
* 
* @author (Austin J) 
* @version (1/4/2016)
*/
public class CO2FootprintTester
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ArrayList <CO2Footprint> CO2 = new ArrayList<CO2Footprint>(5);


        CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(false, true, true, false,1300,.08,4, 1, 450));
        CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, true, false, 1200, .07, 3, 6, 400));
        CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, false, false, 1350, .09, 4, 4,600));
        CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(false, false, false, false, 1400, .1,5,1, 550));
        CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, true, true, 1100, .06, 3, 10, 450));

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(CO2<i>.gasWaste());
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: `CO2<i>` makes no sense. Read an ArrayList tutorial -- use the `get(i)` method.

Comment: `System.out.print(CO2.get(i).gasWaste());`

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, thank you so much. I really knew that and completely forgot. I never would have remembered that though, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is `CO2< i>`, are you forced to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

If not, you can use below 'for' syntax for ArrayList and It will be ok.

```
for(CO2Footprint co2Item: CO2){
    System.out.print(co2Item.gasWaste());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
   System.out.print(CO2.get(i).gasWaste());
```

instead of

```
   System.out.print(CO2<i>.gasWaste());
```

In your full example:

```
import java.util.*;
/**
* Write a description of class CO2FootprintTester here.
* 
* @author (Austin J) 
* @version (1/4/2016)
*/
public class CO2FootprintTester
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      ArrayList <CO2Footprint> CO2 = new ArrayList<CO2Footprint>(5);


      CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(false, true, true, false,1300,.08,4, 1, 450));
      CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, true, false, 1200, .07, 3, 6, 400));
      CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, false, false, 1350, .09, 4, 4,600));
      CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(false, false, false, false, 1400, .1,5,1, 550));
      CO2.add(new CO2Footprint(true, true, true, true, 1100, .06, 3, 10, 450));

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          System.out.print(CO2.get(i).gasWaste());
      }       
    }
}
```